Spring Boot OAuth: Configuration of {bcrypt} client secret
I had a Spring OAuth setup (Auth server, Resource server and Client) up and running perfectly fine (not in production though, only in dev environment) until I had to enable a password encoder in my Auth server, as I needed to save passwords in my database:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

...
}

After that I got a OAuth2AuthenticationException: Client authentication failed: client_secret when I tried to access a secured path in my Client application and tried to login via the Auth server.
I figured out the problem was the misconfiguration in my

Auth server config:
security:
  oauth2:
    authorizationserver:
      client:
        ht-webapp-client:
          registration:
            client-id: "ht-webapp-client"
            client-secret: "{noop}secret"
  ...



and

Client app config:
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        ht-webapp-client-oidc:
          provider: spring
          client-id: ht-webapp-client
          client-secret: secret
  ...



So I changed both to:

Auth server: client-secret: "{bcrypt}$2a$10$OIxoSDHnc.Z8VAyTj0O2yObspW5d.WALrA/yg022oyVWN9Sw/1b1u"
Client app: client-secret: blub

I got the hash by executing spring encodepassword blub on spring-cli just like Josh in his tutorial video.
As you and me would expect, this doesn't resolve my issue because when I try to login the Auth server takes the secret submitted by the client and encodes it using the BCryptPasswordEncoder. But as it uses a different salt, the result is not the same thus the comparison fails leading to the exception.
Debugging results:

org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder#matches:
encodedPassword = "{bcrypt}$2a$10$OIxoSDHnc.Z8VAyTj0O2yObspW5d.WALrA/yg022oyVWN9Sw/1b1u"
rawPassword = "blub"

!this.BCRYPT_PATTERN.matcher(encodedPassword).matches() evaluates to true, so I get the warning Encoded password does not look like BCrypt printed to my console. But why? This is the exact same string I got from my spring-cli! Edit: I found out what went wrong, I am going to answer my own question!


What am I missing here? How am I supposed to deposit a secret in my Auth server configuration which will pass the test? There's gotta be something I miss. Thank you all.

I finally found what was going wrong by debugging org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder#matches which was returning false after all. Here's what you need to know:
If you make use of the BCryptPasswordEncoder by defining the bean in you config, there is no need to prefix the client secret hash by {bcrypt}:

{bcrypt}$2a$10$OIxoSDHnc.Z8VAyTj0O2yObspW5d.WALrA/yg022oyVWN9Sw/1b1u --> Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
$2a$10$OIxoSDHnc.Z8VAyTj0O2yObspW5d.WALrA/yg022oyVWN9Sw/1b1u --> you're fine

Can anybody tell me where I can find this tiny information which just cost me two days?
